# How to make an IF/ELSE statement continue ore restart in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I have this code and I want to know in what kind of loop should I wrap it in so it doesn't exit the console program after the code ends.

```
string command = Console.ReadLine();

if(command == ("help"))
    //gives out a list of commands

else if(command == ("quit"))
    //quits the program

else
    //Sorry, I didn't understand you!
```

Comment: `while`, `do .. while`... I advise you to read an introductory book/tutorial about C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a do-while loop.

```
var validCommands = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
do
{
    if(command == "foo")
        // do stuff
    else if (command == "bar")
        // do stuff
    else
        // invalid
}
while(!validCommands.Contains(command))
```

Answer (score 1):

something like :

```
do {
  string s = Console.ReadLine();
} while (s != "quit")
```